# What happens with the name parameter in MapRoute()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Whats the point of naming the maproute? It confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the route by name in methods such as [RedirectToRoute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoroute%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).

```
return RedirectToRoute("MyRouteName");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would've never thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the url by calling the `Url.RouteUrl` and passing parameters

```
Url.RouteUrl(routeName, RouteValueDictionary)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But what does it mean to generate an url? Isn't the url any random string that gets ticked in your browser, and your routing engine will interpret it and send it to action methods inside controllers?

Comment: They may be scenarios where you'll need to generate the url based on some parameters ... the API won't exist if it wasn't needed i guess :)